# Selecting values of table row using jQuery

Tags: jquery, mvccontrib-grid

I have a table containing dropdown list in each row. Rows doesn't have id property. So, as row doesn't have id property, how can i get selected item of the dropdown list and corresponding ID column's value. for example, if i select an item from the first row i want value of the item and ID column's value, i.e. 204.

[image: table to be manipulated using jQuery]

This is the html code of the above table

```
 <table class="table-1 gapmb40">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Status
            </th>
            <th>
                <a class="sortable" href="">Featured</a>
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a class="sortable" href="">Date Modified</a>
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th>
                ID
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="input-2" name="2">
                    <option value="New">New</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="Live">Live</option>
                    <option value="AccountOnly">AccountOnly</option>
                    <option value="Hide">Hide</option>
                    <option value="Suspended">Suspended</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="">Feature</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="">View</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                07/03/2013
            </td>
            <td style="display: none">
                <a href="">LogOnAs</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                204
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

give all you selectbox a class...say `selectClass` and use jquery class selector.

try this

```
 $('.selectClass').change(function(e){
     alert($(this).val()); //gives you the selected value
     alert($(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(5)').text()); //gives you the related TD which is 4th column and gets its text

     //or
     alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(5)').text()); 
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/7XRZ7/)

Comment: answering this  even though your question is most likely to get closed...please post your related codes also with your question.. so that others can help you...

Comment: bipen,  alert($(this).parent().find('td:eq(3)').text()); is returning me blank value.

Comment: @kaustubhshukla updated try it out...updated fiddle too.. have a look

Comment: thanks a lot bipen...      alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(5)').text()); really worked for me ...

Comment: bipen, i want to update this with some extra jQuery. on change of the dropdown list, i am showing a confirmation dialog box with OK and Cancel button. If user click on cancel button or close the confirmation box, i want previous value of the dropdown to be selected. Ex: referring to the pic added with the question, if someone change the dropdown value from 'Live' to something else and popup has been shown and user cancel it, user will see 'Live' in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If you have table id then you can try this..

```
$("#tbltable tr").click(function() {
    var selectedText = $(this).find('select :selected').text();
    var columnID = this.cells[4].innerHTML.toString();
    alert(selectedText + " , " + columnID);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange=sel_change(this.value,'<%=id%>');></select>
```

so in the javascript function you can get the selected item value and the id of that row

```
<script>

    function sel_change(item,id){
        alert("selected item "+item+"from the id "+id);
    }

</script>
```